# Premake Directive for Including External Static Library

Tags: static, compilation, external, premake

I have an externally built static library (outside of premake).  What kind of library directive do I use to tell it to include that in the make file.  I'm building on OSX and it seems that static libraries need to be included with the ".o" object files in the compile command.  Right now I'm just manually hacking this into the makefile, but it's ugly.  I remember trying to do this for weeks and not finding a solution.  I decided to come back and try again after a few months.

Any ideas?  Maybe there's something painfully obvious.

thx
eris

Comment: Hi, usually you don't have to provide the extension when linking something. For instance 'links { "foo" }' will link to the static lib 'foo'. At least it works like this with vs* actions. What do you use exactly to link your external statib library and what does it generate ?

Comment: I remember what the problem was, Citron.  When I used the links directive on OSX it would always try to link against the shared version of the same library.   For some reason the clang build chain doesn't allow searching statics before dynamics so you have to rename the static and link to that.
thx, eris.